# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 10, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 6]

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to implement custom tflite object detection model in android application in java. When I paste my model and label map I get this error:

```
EE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.soumio.inceptiontutorial, PID: 21661
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:3) with shape [1, 10, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 6].
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:485)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:255)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:216)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:374)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:332)
        at com.soumio.inceptiontutorial.Classify$3.onClick(Classify.java:175)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

My classifier class:

```
public class Classify extends AppCompatActivity {

    // presets for rgb conversion
    private static final int RESULTS_TO_SHOW = 3;
    private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
    private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;

    // options for model interpreter
    private final Interpreter.Options tfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();
    // tflite graph
    private Interpreter tflite;
    // holds all the possible labels for model
    private List<String> labelList;
    // holds the selected image data as bytes
    private ByteBuffer imgData = null;
    // holds the probabilities of each label for non-quantized graphs
    private float[][] labelProbArray = null;
    // holds the probabilities of each label for quantized graphs
    private byte[][] labelProbArrayB = null;
    // array that holds the labels with the highest probabilities
    private String[] topLables = null;
    // array that holds the highest probabilities
    private String[] topConfidence = null;


    // selected classifier information received from extras
    private String chosen;
    private boolean quant;

    // input image dimensions for the Inception Model
    private int DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 640;
    private int DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 640;
    private int DIM_PIXEL_SIZE = 3;

    // int array to hold image data
    private int[] intValues;

    // activity elements
    private ImageView selected_image;
    private Button classify_button;
    private Button back_button;
    private TextView label1;
    private TextView label2;
    private TextView label3;
    private TextView Confidence1;
    private TextView Confidence2;
    private TextView Confidence3;

    // priority queue that will hold the top results from the CNN
    private PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Float>> sortedLabels =
            new PriorityQueue<>(
                    RESULTS_TO_SHOW,
                    new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Float>>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Float> o1, Map.Entry<String, Float> o2) {
                            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
                        }
                    });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // get all selected classifier data from classifiers
        chosen = (String) getIntent().getStringExtra("chosen");
        quant = (boolean) getIntent().getBooleanExtra("quant", false);

        // initialize array that holds image data
        intValues = new int[DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y];

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //initilize graph and labels
        try{
            tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(), tfliteOptions);
            labelList = loadLabelList();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // initialize byte array. The size depends if the input data needs to be quantized or not
        if(quant){
            imgData =
                    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                            DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
        } else {
            imgData =
                    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                            4 * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
        }
        imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // initialize probabilities array. The datatypes that array holds depends if the input data needs to be quantized or not
        if(quant){
            labelProbArrayB= new byte[1][labelList.size()];
        } else {
            labelProbArray = new float[1][labelList.size()];
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_classify);

        // labels that hold top three results of CNN
        label1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1);
        label2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label2);
        label3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label3);
        // displays the probabilities of top labels
        Confidence1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Confidence1);
        Confidence2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Confidence2);
        Confidence3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Confidence3);
        // initialize imageView that displays selected image to the user
        selected_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_image);

        // initialize array to hold top labels
        topLables = new String[RESULTS_TO_SHOW];
        // initialize array to hold top probabilities
        topConfidence = new String[RESULTS_TO_SHOW];

        // allows user to go back to activity to select a different image
        back_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Classify.this, ChooseModel.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // classify current dispalyed image
        classify_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.classify_image);
        classify_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // get current bitmap from imageView
                Bitmap bitmap_orig = ((BitmapDrawable)selected_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                // resize the bitmap to the required input size to the CNN
                Bitmap bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap_orig, DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y);
                // convert bitmap to byte array
                convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);
                // pass byte data to the graph
                if(quant){
                    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArrayB);
                } else {
                    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
                }
                // display the results
                printTopKLabels();
            }
        });

        // get image from previous activity to show in the imageView
        Uri uri = (Uri)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("resID_uri");
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            selected_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // not sure why this happens, but without this the image appears on its side
            selected_image.setRotation(selected_image.getRotation() + 90);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // loads tflite grapg from file
    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd(chosen);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    // converts bitmap to byte array which is passed in the tflite graph
    private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imgData == null) {
            return;
        }
        imgData.rewind();
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        // loop through all pixels
        int pixel = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
                final int val = intValues[pixel++];
                // get rgb values from intValues where each int holds the rgb values for a pixel.
                // if quantized, convert each rgb value to a byte, otherwise to a float
                if(quant){
                    imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 16) & 0xFF));
                    imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 8) & 0xFF));
                    imgData.put((byte) (val & 0xFF));
                } else {
                    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // loads the labels from the label txt file in assets into a string array
    private List<String> loadLabelList() throws IOException {
        List<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("labelmap.txt")));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            labelList.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return labelList;
    }

    // print the top labels and respective confidences
    private void printTopKLabels() {
        // add all results to priority queue
        for (int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); ++i) {
            if(quant){
                sortedLabels.add(
                        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(labelList.get(i), (labelProbArrayB[0][i] & 0xff) / 255.0f));
            } else {
                sortedLabels.add(
                        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(labelList.get(i), labelProbArray[0][i]));
            }
            if (sortedLabels.size() > RESULTS_TO_SHOW) {
                sortedLabels.poll();
            }
        }

        // get top results from priority queue
        final int size = sortedLabels.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            Map.Entry<String, Float> label = sortedLabels.poll();
            topLables[i] = label.getKey();
            topConfidence[i] = String.format("%.0f%%",label.getValue()*100);
        }

        // set the corresponding textviews with the results
        label1.setText("1. "+topLables[2]);
        label2.setText("2. "+topLables[1]);
        label3.setText("3. "+topLables[0]);
        Confidence1.setText(topConfidence[2]);
        Confidence2.setText(topConfidence[1]);
        Confidence3.setText(topConfidence[0]);
    }


    // resizes bitmap to given dimensions
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
}
```

My model and labelmap:
https://www.pastefile.com/vpg57x
https://www.pastefile.com/ncfyht
I tried solution in another stackoverflow question where the person said I need to change the list.
So I deleted the 4 in :

```
imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
```

But if I do that I get BufferOverflow exception. Can somebody help me resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your custom model produces an output tensor with shape [1, 10, 4] not shape [1, 6]. The object detection model usually have multiple outputs instead of generating one output tensor. Typical output signature of the custom object detection model have four outputs like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#output_signature).

Please make sure to understand the output signature of your custom object detection model first.